Two boys switched when they were babies
I'm looking for a film with the following details:

two boys switched when they were still babies
the movie is set in Middle Age
one of them is from a poor family, the other from royal family
the one supposed to be poor becomes king and he is rude (he has black curly hair)
the other one who is supposed to be rich is kind (he has blonde hair, longer)
when they are mature they somehow find about their real identities so they switch places again
there is one scene after they find who they really are, where the black hair man (the ex king) is used as a buffoon and has to run before someone in the royal family, who is riding a horse (probably when they went for hunting)
the movie is in English, I watched it in Romania on TVR1
not Animated
most likely the movie appeared in 90s'-2000's (not later than 2005). That's when I saw it on TV
movie is color 


Sounds like a version of The Prince and the Pauper but there are dozens of those across the years,.

@Paulie_D no, it is not it. Just checked

I've added that detail into your question.  if you remember any further details, please edit them into your question.

This is a bit of a stretch, but you could be thinking of Start the Revolution Without Me (IMDB), a 1970 comedy starring Gene Wilder and Donald Sutherland.
Start is set in France during the late 1700s, and involves not one but two sets of twins, one born to aristocratic parents and the other born to peasants. The twins are mixed up, and one twin from each set ends up with each set of parents.
The main action takes place during the eve of the french revolution. Donald Sutherland and Gene Wilder play the adult twins. The peasant versions are apparently somewhat dim-witted, while the aristocrat set are snobby and unlikable. The two sets get mistaken for each other and caught up in palace intrigues.
According to the IMDB photos, Wilder has dark hair in this film, while Sutherland has blonde/reddish hair.
It's been years since I saw the film, but I recall a notable scene toward the end of the film which you might remember. Up to this point, the aristocratic twins and the peasant twins have managed not to meet each other and have no idea that anyone was switched at birth. The revolution has started, and there's fighting around the ...palace?. Both sets of twins are present, one fighting for the rebels and the other for the aristocracy. At a climactic moment, both sets of twins charge at each other, swords held high, and stop dead when they see each other.

This is not the movie, my movie is not that old. But thanks for your research!

Could it be Man in the Iron Mask?

The Man in the Iron Mask is a 1998 American action drama film
  directed, produced, and written by Randall Wallace, and starring
  Leonardo DiCaprio in a dual role as the title character and villain,
  Jeremy Irons as Aramis, John Malkovich as Athos, Gerard Depardieu as
  Porthos, and Gabriel Byrne as D'Artagnan.[3] The picture uses
  characters from Alexandre Dumas' D'Artagnan Romances and is very
  loosely adapted from some plot elements of The Vicomte de Bragelonne.
The film centers on the aging four musketeers, Athos, Porthos, Aramis,
  and D'Artagnan, during the reign of King Louis XIV and attempts to
  explain the mystery of the Man in the Iron Mask, using a plot more
  closely related to the flamboyant 1929 version starring Douglas
  Fairbanks, The Iron Mask, and the 1939 version directed by James
  Whale, than to the original Dumas book. Like the 1998 version, the two
  aforementioned adaptations were also released through United Artists.
The three musketeers enter a remote prison and smuggle an unnamed
  prisoner in an iron mask out, taking him to the countryside, where
  Aramis reveals that he is Philippe, Louis's identical twin brother.
  Aramis reveals that the night Louis was born, his mother, Queen Anne,
  gave birth to twins. Louis XIII, hoping to avoid dynastic warfare
  between his sons, sent Philippe away to live in the countryside while
  naming Louis as his heir. On his deathbed, Louis XIII revealed
  Philippe's existence to Anne and Louis. Too superstitious to have his
  brother killed, Louis had Philippe imprisoned in the iron mask to keep
  his identity secret, something Aramis reluctantly carried out. Anne
  had been told by her priest that Philippe had died at birth and wished
  to restore Philippe's birthright but couldn't because Louis was now
  king. Aramis's plan is now to redeem himself and save France by
  replacing Louis with Philippe. The musketeers begin training Philippe
  to act and behave like Louis, while Athos develops fatherly feelings
  for him. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_Iron_Mask_(1998_film)

In this film version, as there are several film adaptations, Leonardo DiCaprio plays the twin brothers, Louis and Philippe, but they have similar colored and styled hair

There is another 1998 film version The Face of Alexander Dumas: The Man in the Iron Mask, which was the last version ever made, that features actor Nick Richert in the Louis/Philippe role instead, but I am unfamiliar with how those characters are physically presented.

I really appreciate your research but this is not the movie

It's probably some version of Prince and the Pauper then--I was looking yesterday--there is a 2000 live action version, but the "boys" didn't match the hair descriptions...
